# Find the equivalence class containing the element

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Consider the group G = {1, 3, 5, 7}  under multiplication mod 8. Consider the subgroup H= {1,3}. Find the equivalence class containing the element 5  using the relation ~R.

I am very stuck on this problem. I know that we want to start out with:

5= { x ∈ ??? | x ~ R 5} = {x ∈ ?| (x * 5^-1) ∈ H }   the question marks are where I am confused, and I dont know where to go from here....

Comment: I also know that the inverses of {1, 3, 5, 7} mod 8 are {1, 3, 5, 7} respectively, but I dont know how that helps me.

Comment: What is ~R ? Is it congruence modulo H ?

Comment: Do you mean the coset of $H$ which contains $5$? If so, then it's $5H$, which is...?

Comment: In our textbook it says: Let ~R be defined by a~Rb if and only if ab^-1 ∈ H, then ~R is an equivalence relation on G.

Comment: It asks for the equivalence class which I dont think its the same as 5H, which would give you {5,7}... That seems like the correct answer, but I dont think 5H= the equivalence class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalence class of $5$ is $\{1,3\}\cdot 5 = \{1\cdot 5,\   3 \cdot 5 \} = \{ 5, 7\}$.
Note that the multiplication is done mod $8$ so $3\cdot 5 = 15\  (\text{mod}\  8) = 7$.

Comment: can you explain to my why 5H is the equivalence class?

Comment: Right. $a \simeq 5$ if and only if $a\cdot 5^{-1} \in H$ iff $a\cdot 5^{-1} = h$ iff $a = h \cdot 5 $ so iff $a \in H \cdot 5$.

Comment: Note that right and left is the same in this case but may not be for some non-commutative groups. I modified the answer nevertheless to capture the right form.

Comment: so, would {5, 7} be the subgroup generated by 5 from the group {1, 3, 5, 7}? or would the subgroup generated by 5 just be {5}?

Comment: actually it couldnt just be 5,7 because we generated that from the subgroup rather than the full group. so would the subgroup generated by 5 be {1, 5, 3, 7} again, or just be {5}?

Comment: $5$ generates the subgroup $\{1,5\}$. There are two more subgroups that are not $\{1\}$ or the whole group: $\{1,3\}$ and $\{1, 7\}$. The equivalence class containing $5$ for the relationship determined by the subgroup $H$ is just $H \cdot 5$ and it has as many elements as $H$. By the way, $H$ will be the equivalence class of $1$.